# Need to add a step for unexpected results

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have a script that runs and tells me if a user belongs to a specific AD group which will identify the VPN he is using. When the script runs into a user that is not part of the domain it breaks and does not go any further, I want to ask for help as to adding a piece that will print out that user is not in the system in the output file and continue checking the rest.

Also when I run it for only user I know are in the system it puts their name multiple times with AD groups that they are not part of.

```
Get-Content D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\List1.txt | Foreach-Object {
   $name =  ( ( net user $_ /domain | select-string 'full name' | out-string ).Trim() -split "`r`n" ) |
      Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(29).Trim() -split 'full name' } |
      Where-Object { -Not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } 
      $group =  ( ( net user $_ /domain | select-string '\*' | out-string ).Trim() -split "`r`n" ) |
      Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(29).Trim() -split '\*' } |
      Where-Object { -Not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } 
      $group >> D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\FullList.txt


   $ADgroups = Get-Content D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\FullList.txt

   $VPNgroups = foreach($line in $ADgroups) {
       if ($line -like "VPN-GRP*") {$name + $line >> D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\ADGroups.txt}

   }
}
```

This is the output I am getting when the user is not in the system:

```
net : The user name could not be found.
At line:2 char:17
+    $name =  ( ( net user $_ /domain | select-string 'full name' | out-string ).T ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The user name could not be found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.
Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At line:3 char:24
+       Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(29).Trim() -split 'full name' } |
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

And when they are in the system I am getting them with wrong info IE:

Michael Smith VPN-GRP-1
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-1
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-1
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-1
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-1
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-2
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-2
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-2
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-2
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-2
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-3
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-3
Michael Smith VPN-GRP-3
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-1
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-1
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-1
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-1
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-2
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-2
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-3
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-3
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-3
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-3
Justin Jones VPN-GRP-4
...... continues on for over 1k users
Each user is only a member of one of those AD groups.

Comment: Why are you not just using the AD cmdlets? Would it not be simpler to get the members of the groups, then performs lookups based on that?

Comment: the system I am working on is DMZed and doesnt have the Active Directory module :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that for every single user you're appending their groups to FullList.txt. So with every person you're checking against every previous person's groups as well.

The first adjustment I'll make is to store the output of net user into a variable so that you don't have to run it multiple times, done using `$Query = cmd /c net user 'asdf' /domain 2`>`&1`.

Next, we'll check to see if it found a valid user in an if statement:

```
if ( $Query | Select-String 'The user name could not be found.') {
    "$_ is not a valid user" | Out-File -FilePath D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\ADGroups.txt -Append
  }
```

otherwise, if it is a valid user then we can continue with the rest of the script and extract the name and groups. I took the liberty of simplifying some of the code, and using regex for grabbing the name.

```
$Query | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Full\sName\s+(\w+\s\w+)' } 
    $name = $Matches[1]

    $groups = $Query | select-string '\*' | Out-String |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(29).Trim() -split '\*' -split "`r`n" } |
    Where-Object { -Not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }
```

I removed the step where it outputs to a file, which is then read again by the script, seemed redundant. But lastly we check that one of the groups matches the VPN string:

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    if ($group -like 'VPN-GRP*') { $name + $group | Out-File 'D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\ADGroups.txt' -Append }
```

And that should do it. Let me know if I messed something up, or it's still not working. Here's what it looks like all together:

```
Get-Content D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\List1.txt | Foreach-Object {
  $Query = cmd /c net user $_ /domain 2`>`&1
  if ( $Query | Select-String 'The user name could not be found.') {
    "$_ is not a valid user" | Out-File -FilePath D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\ADGroups.txt -Append
  }
  else {
    $Query | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Full\sName\s+(\w+\s\w+)' } 
    $name = $Matches[1]

    $groups = $Query | select-string '\*' | Out-String |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(29).Trim() -split '\*' -split "`r`n" } |
    Where-Object { -Not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }

    foreach ($group in $groups) {
      if ($group -like 'VPN-GRP*') { $name + $group | Out-File 'D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\ADGroups.txt' -Append }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This script only outputs the last user ID checked into the ADGroups text file when it completes.

Comment: You're right, I missed adding `-Append` to the group Out-File command. I fixed it now though!

Comment: I did the same thing and added that to the script, its working now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd do an ADSI search against the domain controller. No need for the AD cmdlets.

```
$Groups = 'VPN-GRP-1','VPN-GRP-2','VPN-GRP-3','VPN-GRP-4'
$GroupHT = @{}
$LDAP = "DC=domain,DC=com"

ForEach($Group in $Groups){
    $Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=$Group)(objectClass=group))"
    $Searcher = [adsisearcher]$Filter
    $Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$LDAP"
    $Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('Member')|Out-Null
    $Results=$Searcher.FindAll()
    $Members=ForEach($User in $Results.Properties.Item('member')){
        $LDAP = $User -replace '^.+?,(?=DC=)'
        $Filter = "(&(DistinguishedName=$User)(objectClass=user))"
        $Searcher = [adsisearcher]$Filter
        $Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$LDAP"
        $Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('SamAccountName')|Out-Null
        $UserResults=$Searcher.FindAll()
        $objProps=@{SamAccountName=$UserResults.Properties.Item('SamAccountName');FullName=$User -replace "CN=(.+?),.*",'$1'}
        New-Object PSObject -Property $objProps
    }
    $GroupHT.Add($Group,$Members)
}

$Results=ForEach($User in (Get-Content D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\List1.txt)){
    $UserInfo = $GroupHT.GetEnumerator()|?{$User -in $_.Value.SamAccountName}|%{"{0} {1}" -f ($_.Value|?{$_.SamAccountName -eq $User).FullName,$_.Key}
    If(![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($UserInfo)){$UserInfo}Else{Write-Warning "User not found in a group: $user"}
}
$Results | Add-Content 'D:\Scripts\VPNGroup\ADGroups.txt'
```

This will leave you with a hashtable with the group names as keys, and an array of objects with each group member's FullName and SamAccountName. Then it loops through users, references the hashtable to find their group, and if it isn't found outputs a warning to screen. In the end it adds all the found users to a file.